# Javascript loop ignore array index

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

I am attempting to loop over product data where each node of data is in its own index of the array. How can I return all "product-name" or "product-url" values regardless of their index?

My code looks like this

```
var products = res.data.CO;

products.forEach((product, index) => {
    console.log(product);
});
```

I am able to return each entry but not able to use dot or bracket notation to 
only bring back one value from each entry. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn5oL.png

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is the map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another:

```
const productNames = products.map(product => product['product-name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access values using an array like bracket notation

```
var products = res.data.CO;

products.forEach((product, index) => {
    console.log(product['product-name']);
});
```

Or if you just want the product names you could do reduce

s using an array like bracket notation

```
var products = res.data.CO;

// array of product names
products.map(product => product['product-name']);
```